# How do you beat Cytosinor in Calculords

Tags: calculords

Cytosinor spams many mutates, what is a good deck against him? I have not beaten him, so I do not have the cards that you can obtain after doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I started a new game for this answer, and I was able to defeat Cytosinor with the default starting deck as soon as I could fight him (player has to reach level 6 to unlock him).

I missed the victory screen, but here he is with 0 hit points:

[image: Calculords screenshot with Cytosinor defeated]

Having said that, it's more than possible that the game has changed a lot (question was made 4 years ago) and, to be completely honest, Cytosinor was not that easy to defeat and I took some damage.

[Cytosinor](http://calculords.wikia.com/wiki/CYTOSINOR) is the 4th enemy commander in [Calculords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculords), after Fancybot, Stardog, and Cpl. Krak, and he tries to overwhelm you by spamming a lot of [mutates](http://calculords.wikia.com/wiki/Mutate) in all the lanes.

The trick to defeat him (and any other enemy commander of the game, really), is to get the Calculord bonus each turn.

From the [Calculords](http://www.calculords.com/game/) web:

> Okay, here's where it gets tricky: numbers vanish after you use them!
>   If you're clever enough to clear all of your numbers, that's called a
>   CALCULORD BONUS!! It earns you a fresh set of numbers to cast even
>   more cards!

From [How to star nerd: Calculords tips straight from Seanbaby](https://www.pockettactics.com/articles/star-nerd-calculords-tips-from-seanbaby/):

> The most important thing to do each turn is get the first CALCULORD
>   BONUS. Even if you only deploy one or two cards, be sure you can clear
>   all your numbers. If you don't do this, you'll probably get overrun
>   and atomized. The most basic way to Calculord is to make the number
>   you need, then turn the rest of your numbers into a 1 or a 0.

With the Calculord bonus you should be able to follow the pace of Cytosinor constant spam.

As his most scary cards are offensive (red), you can keep them at bay by deploying some pusher (green) units to gain time, while concentrating the rest you have in just one lane.

In any case, for your deck you want easy to deploy cards that require as a casting cost a combination of two numbers at most, unless it's a very special unit with the "Phalanx" ability, for example. Other good unit abilities are "First strike", "Squad 2", and "Armor", but probably not worth the waste of three digits to deploy them.

In my main Calculords game, where all enemy commanders have been defeated, my current deck has these cards from Fancybot and Cpl. Krak (none from Stardog):

**FANCYBOT:**

- NEUTRON SNIPER
- RIFLE SQUAD
- SMC P1 TANK

**CPL KRAK:**

- [ASTRO NINJAS!](http://calculords.wikia.com/wiki/ASTRO_NINJAS!)
- [DARE DEVILS](http://calculords.wikia.com/wiki/DARE_DEVILS)
- SEND THE RESERVES!

If I had difficulties beating Cytosinor, I'd play against Fancybot and Cpl. Krak until getting three copies (max allowed in game) of each of these cards.

Just with some ASTRO NINJAS! in your deck and the advice here, Cytosinor should be considerable easier now.